# In rust, any way to return `rows_affected` from an `sqlx::query_with` along with the rows themselves?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

The sqlx [documentation](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/540baf7df55a372cb79d8636d02b1361a495b344/README.md?plain=1#L309) says the following:

> The `execute` query finalizer returns the number of affected rows, if any, and drops all received results.
> In addition, there are `fetch`, `fetch_one`, `fetch_optional`, and `fetch_all` to receive results.
>
> The `Query` type returned from `sqlx::query` will return `Row<'conn>` from the database. Column values can be accessed
> by ordinal or by name with `row.get()`. As the `Row` retains an immutable borrow on the connection, only one
> `Row` may exist at a time.

Is there any way get both the `rows_affected` and the rows themselves?

I tried running the same query twice in a transaction that I rollback intentionally, but I am already in the middle of a transaction when I receive the sql statement, and I cannot run two transactions in parallel.

Is there a way to do it without running it twice?

I am using rust, the latest sqlx and postgres as the database.

Comment: In case of `fetch_all` isn't the `Vec::len` of the result what you're after? For `fetch_one` it's trivially 1 and for `fetch` you can't know until after you've processed them all.

Comment: `fetch_all` works for `SELECT` statements, but not for `DELETE`, for example. I am executing arbitrary queries. Postgres always knows this information, because in `psql` it tells you both, so it means that `sqlx` may, by design, drop it somewhere for `fetch_all`.

Comment: But you wouldn't `fetch*` a delete statement to begin with⁉

Comment: I execute arbitrary queries. I can switch to using `execute` for all of them. Do you know how I can retrieve the rows (if any), with `execute`? It would lead to the same question being answered, because I need both effects, regardless of the main operation.

Comment: "I execute arbitrary queries" I don't know what you're building, but this has "SQL Injection" written all over it :-) But FWIW, there is PgQueryResult::rows_affected() which sounds is what you're looking for? https://docs.rs/sqlx-postgres/0.7.2/sqlx_postgres/struct.PgQueryResult.html#method.rows_affected

Comment: Is it an injection when I am voluntarily executing arbitrary queries? :-) It's just a small wrapper. `PgQueryResult` is how I get the rows modified now, but it is only returned by `execute`, in general for `sqlx`. I now see in the documentation a `fetch_many` for postgres, which has return type either `PgQueryResult` or a `PgRow`, it may be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also need the `futures` crate:

```ini
[dependencies]
futures = { version = "0.3.28", default-features = false }
sqlx = { version = "0.7.2", features = ["runtime-tokio", "postgres"] }
```

Then you can do shenanigans like this:

```rs
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use sqlx::{postgres::PgPoolOptions, Either, PgPool, Row};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    # ...

    do_query(
        &pool,
        "INSERT INTO todos (description) VALUES ('One'), ('Two') RETURNING id",
    )
    .await;
    do_query(&pool, "DELETE FROM todos").await;
}

async fn do_query(pool: &PgPool, query: &str) {
    let prefix = query.split_whitespace().next().unwrap();

    let mut results = sqlx::query(query).fetch_many(pool);

    while let Some(result) = results.next().await {
        let either = result.unwrap();
        match either {
            Either::Left(res) => {
                let num = res.rows_affected();
                println!("[{prefix}] affected {num} rows");
            }
            Either::Right(row) => {
                let num = row.len();
                println!("[{prefix}] fetched {num} rows");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return

```
[INSERT] fetched 1 rows
[INSERT] fetched 1 rows
[INSERT] affected 2 rows
[DELETE] affected 2 rows
```

Comment: Seems wasteful for `sqlx` to require iterating the rows like that to get both, but this seems to be the current best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say your usecase is somewhat non-standard, so I understand that support is limited ;-)